# Unable to use prepared statement to insert data in partitioned table

Tags: java, sql, impala

I am trying to insert data into partitioned impala table using java prepared statements. Insert is working good with non partitioned but I am getting error with partitioned tables.

I need to check performance difference of partitioned vs non partitioned , I feel best would be to use prepared statements for the connection.

```
create_query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_raw_flow_v9 (source_ip string,destination_ip string,protocol_number int,) partitioned by (year int) stored as parquet";

    private static final String sqlCompiledQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_raw_flow_v9 (source_ip,destination_ip,protocol_number" +
            "PARTITION (year) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";


    private static Connection connectViaDS() throws Exception {
        Connection connection = null;

        Class.forName("com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver");

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL);

        return connection;

    }


# my try block

try {
            connection = connectViaDS();

            connection.setAutoCommit(false);

            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlCompiledQuery);

            while(counter <total) {

                for (int index = 1; index <= records; index++) {

                    counter++;

                    preparedStatement.setString(1, "s_ip" + String.valueOf(index));

                    preparedStatement.setString(2, "d_ip" + String.valueOf(index));

                    preparedStatement.setInt(3, protocol_no + index);

                    preparedStatement.setInt(4, yr + flag);

                    preparedStatement.addBatch();

                }
                preparedStatement.executeBatch();

                preparedStatement.clearBatch();

                connection.commit();

                System.out.println("Counter = "+counter);

                flag++;


            }

        }
```

I don't know whether I am making mistake in using prepared statement or there is something else. I am able to insert value into partition table using

```
"INSERT INTO tbl_raw_flow_v9 (source_ip,destination_ip,protocol_number) PARTITION (year) VALUES ("s_ip","d_ip",234,2010);
```

When I use prepaid statement I get following error in java-

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][JDBC](11420) Error, parameter metadata not populated.
    at com.cloudera.exceptions.ExceptionConverter.toSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.jdbc.common4.C4SPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.jdbc.jdbc41.S41PreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.jdbc.jdbc41.JDBC41ObjectFactory.createPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.ImpalaJDBC41ObjectFactory.createPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.jdbc.common.SConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at impala_test.writeInABatchWithCompiledQuery(impala_test.java:100)
    at impala_test.main(impala_test.java:52)
```

It would be really helpful if someone can throw light on this.

Comment: You are missing `)` after `protocol_number`

Comment: I had truncated my query to post here but fixing that didn't worked , can I use prepaid statement on partitioned tables,  I can't find any article on this..

Comment: I see no reason why not, but it could be a bug in the JDBC driver. Did you try without using `PARTITION` clause, i.e. `"INSERT INTO tbl_raw_flow_v9 (source_ip, destination_ip, protocol_number, year) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"` ?

Comment: @Andreas its strange for simple statement I need to specify partition while for prepared statement its working without partition.

Comment: It would likely always work without `PARTITION`. You only need the `PARTITION` syntax if one for more of the partition values are constant. --- Anyway, it looks like a bug in the Cloudera Impala JDBC driver, so you should report it. Until they fix it, you now have a workaround.